# Adding class to element using Javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, user-agent

I want to add a class to an element depending on what browser they are using. This is what I have:

```
var browser = navigator.userAgent;

if (browser.match("Firefox")){
  $(".dollar").addClass("ff");
}
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: The HTML

```
<p class="dollar">$</p>
```

Comment: Please add the html code

Comment: In what since is it not working? Walk through the code with your debugger.

Comment: well this work [browser.match(/Firefox/g)](https://jsfiddle.net/56bftwtd/)

Comment: Do not use browser sniffing. Use feature detection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a document (DOM) ready wrapper:

```
var browser = navigator.userAgent;

jQuery(function( $ ){             // DOM is now ready

  if (browser.match("Firefox")){
    $(".dollar").addClass("ff");  // and .dollar is parsed
  }

});
```

Test this ***[jsBin demo](http://output.jsbin.com/qimoco/1/)*** example in Firefox

Comment: Thank you @Roko This worked perfectly

Comment: You're welcome @Ruby

Answer (score 0):

Because navigator.userAgent returns
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0"

which of course doesn't match "Firefox" in your if statement, so thus your if statement is false...

You probably want to try :

```
if (navigator.userAgent.search("Firefox/") > -1)
```

as your if - that should see Firefox - then use Chrome/ for a chrome test

[edited for if suggestion]

Comment: It matches for me. The string contains "Firefox", so I don't see why it shouldn't match.

Comment: Thank you for your response. As what @Roko suggested, I needed the DOM to be fully loaded first. So my initial browser.match("Firefox") still works, it just needed it to be wrapped in a function. I tested out yours, it worked as well. Thank you!